# python virtual environment change

Tags: django, virtual, environment

I am a beginner for django framework. I am working on multiple tutorial projects. According to best practices , I use different virtual environments for different projects.

I have a problem. When I want to switch to another project , even through I deactivate virtual environment of closed project , my browser still looks to the virtual environment that I deactivated. So , I can not display my new project at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ . It still display the older one.

Can you please show me the way?

Thanks.

Comment: did you kill the server of the previous project (Ctrl-C) before starting the server of the new project

Comment: I just run 'deactivate' method at cmd .

Comment: you need to kill the server as well, the virtualenv has nothing to do with the running server

Comment: In the virtual machine, I did as you said (used ctrl + C) ; but it did not worked. (venv) E:\DjangoProjects\venv\Scripts>

Comment: Trivial, but did you switch your active virtual environments to the proper one?

Answer (score 1):

deactivating the virtualenv does not automatically kill the running server.  you need to kill the server (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) of the previous project, before starting the server of the new project.